# Reusing parts of Mongoose schema such as common fields between models

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema which shares multiple fields between my model. Here are a simple representation of the schemas.

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   productName: String,
   productId: String,
   productAltCode: String,
   description: String,
}

 const cartSchema: new mongoose.Schema({
   productId: String,
   productAltCode: String,
   ...
 }
```

Here I have 2 fields which are the same in both models, productId and productAltCode. Is there a way to not duplicate in both schemas? I have this type of scenario with other objects in my model and just think there may a way to not duplicate the fields

Answer (score 1):

You can define a shared object, and use object destructuring.

```js
const product = {
   productId: String,
   productAltCode: String,
};

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   ...product,
   productName: String,
   description: String,
});

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   ...product,
   /* rest of your model */
});
```